# Number Theory Problem $a+b+c=5^{1402}$ where $a,b$ and $c$ have the same amount of digits

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Assume $a+b+c=5^{1402}$. Find All integer values for $a$, $b$ and $c$ where $a$, $b$ and $c$ have the same amount of digits.

I honestly tried to multiply both sides by $2^{1402}$, which I think is pretty irrelevant. I have no Idea how to solve something like this. I would be happy if anyone could help.

Comment: On this site, you're expected to share the source of your problem and what you've tried to solve it.

Comment: If the restriction on the variables were $a,b,c>0$, this is a case for [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)). Now, what does it mean for $a,b,c$ to have, say, $3$ digits. It means that $99<a,b,c<1000$. The condition $99<a,b,c$ is easy to transform in the condition in *stars and bars* by the change of variable $a=99+a', b=99+b', c=99+c'$. Then $a',b',c'>0$ is the same as $a,b,c>99$. So, you can use *stars and bars* to count the number of solutions satisfying $a,b,c>99$.

Comment: From these you can subtract the solutions satisfying $a\geq1000$ and those with $b\geq 1000$, and those with $c\geq1000$. Note that you should do [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), since the solutions with $a,b\geq 1000$ are counted double, and those with $a,b,c\geq1000$ are counted triple.

Comment: You can do the work in general, since $n$ digits means the inequalities $10^n-1<a,b,c<10^n$. Then sum the results for all $n$.

Comment: There are infinitely many solutions. For $n$ sufficiently large the numbers
\begin{eqnarray}
a&=&10^n+5^{1402},\\
b&=&10^n,\\
c&=&-10^n.\\
\end{eqnarray}
have the same number of digits. Definitely $n\geq1402$ is sufficiently large. There is no sensible way to list all solutions. What is the source of this question?